# Mostrar datos de un foreach en una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una tabla HTML con un id llamado `"tabla-de-datos-body"`, y tengo un arreglo de datos llamado `"Datos"` , a través de inputs lleno ese arreglo, el arreglo se llena correctamente pero a la hora de querer imprimir los datos en la tabla sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito que se despliegue en linea recta, el primera dato en producto, el segundo en cantidad y el tercero en precio, mi arreglo lo recorro con la siguiente función de javascript:

```html
function addProdsTemp() {

    var tabladatos = document.getElementById('tabla-de-datos-body');
    let datos = [];

    var producto = document.getElementById('producto').value;
    var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
    var precio = document.getElementById('precio').value;

    datos.push(producto, cantidad, precio);

    datos.forEach((el, index) => {
       tabladatos.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+ el +"</td></tr>";
    });
}
```

Mi maquetación HTML de la tabla es la siguiente:

```
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Producto</th>
         <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
         <th scope="col">Precio</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tabla-de-datos-body">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

¿Cómo podría imprimir esos datos en la tabla en linea recta?

Comment: y el `tbody`? no creo que un `tr` pueda ser hijo directo de `table`. Estructuralmente creo que es `<table><thead/><tbody/><tfoot/></table>`. Tal vez quieras leer un poco más acerca de las [tablas en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Comment: En donde se ubica el id `"tabla-de-datos-body"`? Muéstranos tu código html de tu tabla, posiblemente haya un error de etiquetas.

Comment: Adjunto el código de la tabla para que valides el HTML, los datos son:  datos['1','2','3'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cada **`push`** que hagas en tu arreglo, deberías ingresar a las posiciones de sus elementos para cada ciclo que realices. Para esto, tendrías que iterar el arreglo e ingresar a dichas posiciones, yo utilizaría ciclo **`for`**. Tu código sería el siguiente:

```js
function addProdsTemp() {

  var tabladatos = document.getElementById('tabla-de-datos-body');
  let datos = [];

  var producto = document.getElementById('producto').value;
  var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
  var precio = document.getElementById('precio').value;

  datos.push(producto, cantidad, precio);

  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    tabladatos.innerHTML += "<td>" + datos[i++] + "</td>" + "<td>" + datos[i++] + "</td>" + "<td>" + datos[i++] + "</td>";
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Producto:</span></br>
<input id="producto" type="text">
</br>
<span>Precio:</span></br>
<input id="cantidad" type="number">
</br>
<span>Cantidad:</span></br>
<input id="precio" type="number">
</br></br>
<button onclick="addProdsTemp()">Agregar</button>

<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Producto</th>
         <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
         <th scope="col">Precio</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tabla-de-datos-body">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Excelente, es la solución que estaba buscando! , gracias Cris.